# Cannot add comments to my own post

Tags: support, status-completed, comment

I am trying to comment on my own, active bounty, open question, here:
[Classify users by the pages they liked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167922/classify-users-by-the-pages-they-liked)

and for some reason the page is not responding to my click on the "add comment" button.

I am using Firefox with windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see anything about either the post or your account that would lead this to happen (unless you were doing it from a second account).

I do occasionally have temporary issues of a similar nature (with Firefox, and it has happened in both Windows 7 and 8) that are usually resolved by reloading the page, restarting the browser, or re-logging into the site. One time it didn't resolve until I restarted the computer.

Comment: thanks, apparently something broke in firefox